# Long term survival at Tranquility base?

Tags: mars, the-moon

What are the current estimates for the likelihood for a human to survive one year on a true Moon-base (first) vs a Mars-base (first), and what role are such estimates playing in NASA's decision to recommend which body to colonize first?

Comment: Clarification: Yes, it has already been decided that we will return to manned Lunar orbit before we attempt manned Martian orbit, but I'm asking about "living on the body's surface" here, and not about orbiting bases.

Comment: The chance of survival would drive the mission design (in order to reach a desired minimum) and therefore the cost.

Comment: I think it works the other way round. You start with the acceptable level of risk which effectively determines the cost of doing anything. Then you see if that  gives you an acceptable cost/science+publicity tradeoff for some mission design.

Comment: Agreed. With current technology, we can get the chance of survival to 100% on both the Moon and Mars, it's just a matter of budget. And there are no definite plans for either, so no real-life risk assessments we can use to answer this question.

Comment: The way it's supposed to be (when politicians don't interfere) is that scientific needs drive what missions are going to happen.